# Need to fix time conversion to hh:mm

Tags: java

I am doing a time conversion program in Java and I need to fix the code. When I try to display 3:04 it will show 3:4. I need to fix  to show zeros in front of a number less than ten with no if statements and only importing `java.util.Scanner` and `java.text.NumberFormat`. And it has to be in one class. I would like to finish it by tonight. If anyone can help I would appreciate it. Here is the code below. I have already imported these two java classes mentioned above.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    final int MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60;
    int Minutes, Hours, InputedMinutes; 

    System.out.println("Enter a number in minutes: ");
    InputedMinutes = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();

    Hours = InputedMinutes/MINUTES_IN_HOUR;
    Minutes = InputedMinutes%MINUTES_IN_HOUR;

    System.out.println("Your time is " + Hours + ":" + Minutes);    
}
```

Comment: I am using Java 1.7 for this.

Answer (score 3):

Use `format`:

```
System.out.format("%d:%02d", Hours, Minutes);
```

See the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for format specifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `printf` and use date time formatter like the following

```
Date date = new Date(); // For Date objects from java.util.date

System.out.printf("Clock time is = %1$tH:%1$tM", date); // Prints hour and minute of the local clock time.
```

But you are displaying a number format which you can do using:

```
System.out.printf("%d:%02d", Hours, Minutes);
```

Or using format method:

```
System.out.format("%d:%02d", Hours, Minutes);
```

**UPDATE**

Since your last comment about using NumberFormat (or concrete classes), the following should also work in your case (see it in action on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/DXEXMF)):

```
int hours = 30;
int minutes = 3; // or could be 30;

/* 
 * Shows two digits and replaces with 0 if absent (if you use 0)
 *
 * If you use # instead of 0, it will NOT SHOW the leading 0
 *
 */

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00"); 

String formattedHours = df.format(hours);
String formattedMinutes = df.format(minutes);

System.out.printf("Clock hours and minutes = %s:%s", formattedHours, formattedMinutes);
```

For further information, you can consult Oracle's [Customizing Formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is now displaying the 0 in front of the number.

Comment: Do you know another way using number format and not the format?

Comment: @Wasosauce        How do you mean?

Comment: I am not sure but if I use what you gave above do I have to import the java.text.NumberFormat? My teacher said that he wanted us to practice with it. I am not sure what Number format to use and was wondering if you knew what one to use?

Comment: @Wasosauce       My original answer doesn't require you to use NumberFormat. But check the update to see if this is what you needed. BTW `NumberFormat` is an abstract class and you actually end up using `ChoiceFormat` or `DecimalFormat` for this type of things. I know that youre teacher asked you to try these, but I would say that it is an overkill for displaying some simple numbers.